# Rails Basic Installation Issue with 'rails new blog'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here's the error:

```
/Users/paulpedrazzi/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:239:in `mkdir': Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /blog (Errno::EACCES)
```

I have latest sqlite and ruby. Looks like permissions, but not sure how to solve.  Appreciate any help.

Comment: Check the current user permissions for the project folder.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you either own or have write permission on the current working directory. Use chown or chmod.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like issue might have been as I was in the root when installing? I created a subfolder and it seemed to work.  For now...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linux/ubuntu, you can do something like this to give permissions to your user in the desired folder:

```sh
chown -R $USER:$USER blog/
```